# Where can i buy propane/ butane gas cylinder for camping in Turkey?

Tags: turkey, camping, istanbul

The question pretty much says it; I tried a couple of gas stations and stores but didn't find anything; I'm in Istanbul Buyukcekmece zone/

Comment: This [ancient post](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/europe-eastern-europe-the-caucasus/topics/buying-camping-gas-in-turkey) gives some clues. Some people just bought local stoves which are a different style.

Comment: What system?  Primus / Campingaz / other?

Comment: @gerrit my stove looks like campigaz.

Comment: Did you try hardware stores?  In some countries they sell campingaz (in the garden/barbecue section).

Comment: @gerrit no from their looks, it seemed like they don't have it; but i must try them anyway; thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can find them online if you search for "Kamp Ocağı".
Hardware stores in shopping malls like Tekzen, Koçtaş, Praktiker will most likely have them. Also Decathlon stores sell them on their camping section with tents and sleeping bags. Ask for stock by calling before going to store though.